# Openshift Origin run-app against insecure registry yields stuck pod with "Error while pulling image"

Tags: docker, rhel, openshift-origin

I am using Openshift Origin in a Docker container and pulled in an image from the Docker registry (a container on the same RHEL host VM) using:

```
oc new-app --insecure-registry=true --docker-image=mtl-vm375:5000/jenkins:1.0
```

That command seemed to work fine at the time.  However, the pod stays as "ContainerCreating" and the result from kubectl describe pods:

```
OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENT_NAME:        jenkins-1
OPENSHIFT_DEPLOYMENT_NAMESPACE:   default
 Conditions:
  Type          Status
  Ready         False
Volumes:
  deployer-token-3bls9:
Type:       Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
  SecretName: deployer-token-3bls9
Events:
  FirstSeen     LastSeen        Count   From                    SubobjectPath   Type            Reason          Message
  ---------     --------        -----   ----                    -------------   --------        ------          -------
  2h            4m              33      {kubelet mtl-vm375}                     Warning         FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ErrImagePull: "Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/openshift/origin-pod/images: dial tcp 10.230.22.20:443: connection refused"

2h    6s      652     {kubelet mtl-vm375}             Warning FailedSync      Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "POD" with ImagePullBackOff: "Back-off pulling image \"openshift/origin-pod:v1.1.5\""
```

Has an error that shows it is trying to use https, which I am guessing (but am not sure) is the error, as I do not have https correctly set up with certificates yet:

Per other advice on Stackoverflow, I have added these environment variables to the Origin image:
    KUBE_ENABLE_INSECURE_REGISTRY=true
    EXTRA_DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry

I have also had similar results with:
    KUBE_ENABLE_INSECURE_REGISTRY=true\
    EXTRA_DOCKER_OPTS="--insecure-registry 10.230.22.20"

Version information:

```
[root@mtl-vm375 origin]# oc version 
oc v1.1.5-52-gd58f979 kubernetes v1.2.0-36-g4a3f9c5
```

and

```
[root@mtl-vm375 ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.centos.x86_64
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7.centos
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version:
 Go version:   go1.4.2
Git commit:   a01dc02/1.8.2
 Built:
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: did you already tried this command with --loglevel=5? + are you able to pull the image manually after performing a docker login on your registry? + Is you registry a real docker registry or an "openshift" registry

Comment: The 'best' way is to secure your OpenShift registry. Tag your jenkins image and push it to your OpenShift registry (expose your registry when you want to push from outside your cluster). Than OpenShift is able to use the image everywhere on the cluster

Comment: Even with command `oc new-app --loglevel=5 --insecure-registry=true --docker-image=mtl-vm375:5000/jenkins:1.0`
there is no more logging provided:
`[root@mtl-vm375 origin]# oc logs jenkins-1-deploy
 Error from server: container "deployment" in pod "jenkins-1-deploy" is waiting to start: ContainerCreating`

Right now, I am using the real docker registry, not the openshift one and can pull it out of Docker repository manually no problem.  I haven't tried it the other way, where it is pushed to Openshift's registry itself.  That's a good suggestion.  I will give that a try.

Comment: tag your image as service-ip:5000/project/image. You you choose openshift as project than you'll create an image-stream which is known by the whole cluster. When you want to push from the outside to your registry you'll need to exopse it (docker-regsitry.xxx:443/..).

Comment: I tried to perform what you want with another registry. I'll post is as an answer. You can also try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the steps I performed to use an image from another Docker registry (even outside my cluster).

My registry:

```
https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000
```

I create the project (in OS) to where I want to push.

```
$ oc new-project test
```

I'm inside the project and I'll create a secret so that my openshift is able to access my registry:

```
$ oc secrets new-dockercfg mysecret --docker-server=https://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000 --docker-username=testuser --docker-password=testpassword --docker-email=any@mail.com
```

add secret to serviceaccounts

```
$ oc secrets add serviceaccount/default secrets/mysecret --for=pull    
$ oc secrets add serviceaccount/builder secrets/mysecret
```

import image stream

```
$ oc import-image --insecure ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5000/test/name-of-image:1 --confirm
```

Now you're able to create a

```
oc new-app --insecure-registry <image-stream-name>:tag
```

A better way is to push your images to the OpenShift registry. Than it isn't necessary to create a secret and to perform the `oc import`.
You're able to expose a registry (secure registry) so you can access the registry from outside your cluster to push images.

Comment: Thank you, lorenzvth7! I followed your instructions in the most recent post about another Docker registry, and that worked! Our server is not able to reach Docker hub or similar sites because of firewall limits, so I had errors about origin-pod & origin-deployer, which I fixed by tagging and pushing to Docker.

I will eventually move to an Openshift registry, although I suspect the firewall will make that more challenging. Right now I still have the new-app deploy failed because of a different error. We can consider this closed. I'll research my current issue and open a new question if needed.

Answer (score 0):

**If you struggling with the Openshift Builder after you updated the import :tag via an republishing (reimporting)**

- Your OpenShift builds seems not to use the latest image-tag which you had published via oc import-image..

  1. open the "Builder-Configuration of your app",
  2. go to the section "Image Configuration"
  3. and switch the "Build From" value from "Docker Image Repository" to "Image Stream Tag"
  4. and select the Namespace, Image Stream and Tag there.

**Overview of Builder Configuration:**

[image: Builder Configuration of app]

- Set a new value to "Docker Image Repository" has not helped.
- Set the checkbox at "Always pull the build..." has also not helped.

Change this ...

[image: Builder Configuration of your app]

to this ...

[image: Builder Configuration changed of your app]